# Sustituir las filas vacias o con valores nulos en una columna por los de otra

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame  con dos columnas (`A` y `B`), en la columna `a` hay filas que están vacías (pueden ser `"nan"` o `" "`) ¿Cómo puedo hacer para tomar los valores de la columna `B` y pasarlos a la `A` pero solo rellenando los valores que están vacíos o son nulos?. Por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iDf2= {'a': [' ', 'juan', 'nan'],
       'b': ['2', '5', 'martina']}
iDf2 = pd.DataFrame(iDf2)
```

quiero que me quede así:

```
 iDf2= {'a': ['2','juan','martina'],
        'b': ['2','5','martina']}
```

Comment: El problema es en la base de datos o dentro de python?

Comment: Me añado a la duda de gbianchi, creo que falta bastante contexto para poder dar la mejor solución posible. Además de `base-de-datos` usas `pandas` como etiqueta (y `datatables`...). Suponiendo que sea un `DataFrame` de Pandas  en realidad me surgen más dudas ¿Pueden faltar filas en ambas columnas?¿Pueden faltar las mismas filas en ambas (o ser ' ' en una y 'nan' en otra) y de ser así que se hace?¿Siempre tienes dos columnas?¿Si hay más de dos cual es el protocolo para elegir la columna para obtener los datos si en una faltan?

Comment: @gbianchi perdon es verdad me falto aclarar, uso pandas ya que estoy trabajando con dataframes , python, uso pandas y numpy . Mi idea es que de ese dataframe pueda tomar de la columna B los datos que en la columna A faltan o estan en Nan.. y completarlos. Gracias.

Comment: @FJSevilla fijate de ordenar los tags porque no me queda nada claro que tiene que ver db aca...

Comment: ¿Emaa entonces solo habría que mirar la columna `a` y los datos que falten completarlos con los de la misma fila de `b` sin tener en cuenta nada más (otras columnas, datos que falten en `b`, etc)? Otra cosa, haces referencia valores vacíos, en tu primera fila tienes un espacio `' '`, no una cadena vacía `''`, es importante porque no es lo mismo y la forma de abordarlo difiere.

Comment: @FJSevilla claro es solamente completar los valores que faltan y los nan con los valores de la fila B, pero en los que A esta completo no… sino solo cambiaria el nombre de la columna B y listo :p jajaja , . Con respecto al '' " puede que sea un espacio o vacio o nan... la idea es completarlo . Espero me puedas ayudar  . Mil gracias :D

Answer (score 3):

Si tus valores fueran verdaderamente valores nulos podrías usar simplemente el método `fillna`:

```
iDf2.a.fillna(iDf2.b, inplace=True)
```

El problema es que lo que consideras valores vacíos no son realmente valores nulos, por ejemplo una cadena con un espacio no va ser considerados como `NaN` por Pandas por defecto. Ante esto tienes dos opciones:

- Normalizar la columna o el DataFrame al completo previamente pasando esos valores considerados como "vacíos" a `NaN` y luego aplicar `fillna`. Esto es especialmente relevante si cargas el DataFrame desde un csv (`pandas.read_csv`) o usas `pandas.read_table` por ejemplo, en el cual puedes usar el argumento `na_values` para especificar que debe ser considerado como `NAN`, aparte de los valores que ya son considerados por defecto como tales:

  ```
  import io

  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  file = io.StringIO('''\
  a,b
  ,13
   ,2
  juan,5
  nan,martina
  ''')
  ```

  ---

  ```
  >>> iDf2 = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str, na_values=[" "])
  >>> iDf2

        a        b
  0   NaN       13
  1   NaN        2
  2  juan        5
  3   NaN  martina

  >>> iDf2.a.fillna(iDf2.b,  inplace=True)
  >>> iDf2

           a        b
  0       13       13
  1        2        2
  2     juan        5
  3  martina  martina
  ```

  > Por defecto se se parsean como valores nulos `'-1.#IND'`, `'1.#QNAN'`, `'1.#IND'`, `'-1.#QNAN'`, `'#N/A'`,`'N/A'`, `'NA'`, `'#NA'`, `'NULL'`, `'NaN'`, `'-NaN'`, `'nan'`, `'-nan'`, además de las cadenas vacías.
- Si lo anterior no es posible, simplemente puedes crear una máscara boolena con los valores que consideras "vacíos" (`pandas.Series.isin` puede ser una buena opción) y asignarles en tal caso los valores de la columna `b`.

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np



  data = {'a': ['', ' ','juan','nan', np.nan],
          'b': ['13', '2','5','martina', 'foo']}

  iDf2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
  nans = iDf2.a.isin(('', ' ', 'nan', np.nan))
  iDf2.a[nans] = iDf2.b
  ```

  Salida:

  > ```
  > >>> iDf2
  >          a        b
  > 0       13       13
  > 1        2        2
  > 2     juan        5
  > 3  martina  martina
  > 4      foo      foo
  > ```

Comment: Muchisimassss Ggaciassss de verdad. me encantaria saber todo lo que vos sabes :(

Comment: Gracias me salvaste el día, tenia la misma duda. El tema es que esos valores Nan, son un dolor de cabeza después para gráficar o usar algunas funciones.